# Can't resolve './util' multiply times in react webpack app

Tags: reactjs, npm, webpack, node-modules, yarnpkg

I try to add some modules in my app and when i try to compile it, it caught 
[such errors](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OsZfW.png). By the way i only import module to js file and dont even use it.

Here is [my folder structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RFJp4.png). I try to import in index.js in createwaiver folder (2nd highlight).

I tried to check my webpack config, but there js extension allowed ([copied config file](https://github.com/vldrsk/webpack-config-test/blob/master/Base.js)).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jXeJz.png) is my src/util folder and one of its components thats renders other components in async way

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not 100% sure but I believe your problem is that `util` alias you have on line 208 in your webpack config:

```
util: `${this.srcPathAbsolute}/util/`
```

it means all import `'util/....'` will resolve to `yourrootfolder/src/util`, I'm not sure what you have there in that folder but I'd start with removing that line or renaming it to:

```
waiverutil: `${this.srcPathAbsolute}/util/
```

or similar and go through your code and remove all your `'util/...'` imports to `waiverutil/....`
If that doesn't help let me know, also try posting some more stuff like your imports and /src/util folder.

Comment: I add src/util folder screenshot. I'll try to rename everything with your advice, but may be this screenshot will tell smth more.

Comment: Well, looks like a solution! Thanks a lot! The problem realy was in names of folder and package.

Answer (score 0):

In your `resolve.alias` property, you have an alias defined as `util: '${this.srcPathAbsolute}/util/'`. This is causing the errors because anywhere in your app files and `node_modules` directory that an `import` or `require` statement includes `util` at the beginning of the path, that path will be rewritten incorrectly to start with `./src/util/`.

This alias:

```
resolve: {
  alias: {
    util: `${this.srcPathAbsolute}/util/`
  }
}
```

needs to be renamed to something else to avoid conflicting with the `util` package that many packages import. Because of this, you'll also need to change the paths starting with `util` in your app files to match this change.